# Negation in Thompson's algorithm?

Tags: regex, algorithm, state-machine, nfa

I was reading this for learning how to write state machines for regular expressions

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction

However I only see things like union, concatenation, Kleene star, but nothing on negation, which is mentioned here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton#Closure_properties

What would the construction be for that?

Comment: Thompson is DFA, it does not support negative lookarounds (if you mean that).

Comment: You certainly did not mean DFA, but NFA (and actually, ε-NFA).  And the question of negation is perfectly valid, negative lookaheads are a different conception, of used to simulate the first one.

Answer (score 3):

The Thompson automaton is quite inappropriate for negation: it is not deterministic and actually uses plenty of spontaneous transitions (which are also a source of nondeterminism).  On the contrary, the [Brzozowski automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brzozowski_derivative) is very well suited for negation, intersection, and more generally all the Boolean functions.

You may toy with Vcsn to experiment similar constructions.  It actually even supports weighted expressions and several more operators.  [This page](http://vcsn-sandbox.lrde.epita.fr/notebooks/Doc/Stackoverflow.ipynb) contains several examples showing how to convert an extended regex into an automaton.

[Redgrep](http://vcsn-sandbox.lrde.epita.fr/notebooks/Doc/Stackoverflow.ipynb) implements the Brzozowski method.  In [this very nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMhqlRBfVX4) the designer explains how this works.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly makes a NFA "nondeterministic" vs. a DFA "deterministic". They both look almost exactly the same to me except the DFA is just a more condensed/simplified version of the NFA. You can still make choices at each node and traverse along valid paths to accepting states just the same.

Comment: I have no idea what definition you are actually reading, but first note that, by definition, any DFA is an NFA.  The converse, of course, does not hold.  So for instance `0 -- a --> 1, 0 -- a --> 2`, is not deterministic in state 0: there is a choice, either go to state 1 or state 2 from state 0 with the letter `a`.

Comment: Yes but you can do that in both an NFA and DFA

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "that".  What is clear is that you cannot have `0 -- a --> 1, 0 -- a --> 2` in a DFA.  If you don't see why, you should read again the definition of a DFA.

Comment: I am using online NFA to DFA converters (such as here http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa ) and I don't see the difference. Even in the DFA you can do 0-a-1 and 0-a-2

Comment: You may repeat that as many times as you want, it will not change the fact that it is completely false.  Before answering, read carefully a definition of determinism (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).

Answer (score 0):

I think negation can be constructed equally with alternation, for example , ^0 and 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9 are the same. Negation can be used only on one letter, and there is a finite set of letters. So negation can be considered as a complementary sign as well (in my opinion).